# LED matrix on keyboard

Tags: led, led-matrix, keyboard

I want to build a keyboard from scratch which will be illuminated as well (one LED per key/switch). Due to the fact that I don't need some fancy stuff, just turn the LEDs on/off, can I connect entire columns of LEDs per I/O port of the MC, or I should control them intividually as several schematics suggest?

The reason being, I run out of ports sould I connect them individually. I understand that the answer depends on the amaunt of current the LEDs need  and each port supports, yet I would like to know if someone has any experience on that.

To be specific, I want to connect at most seven LEDs per port on a Teensy board. I am not sure about the voltage because I haven't decided yet which exactly board to use.

By the way, are there any specific LEDs (color or type) which are brighter than others without consuming much current?

Any opinions would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to connect the LEDs to the teensy?

Comment: Are there any alternatives?

Comment: probably there are, what is your goal?

Comment: My goal is to use the least possible ports in order to control the LEDs

Answer (score 2):

maybe just unse one GPIO on the teensy to control a transitor that controls all the LEDs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/248324)

Comment: @TonyM would you care to elaborate?